# TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This code gives no errors:

```
r = df1.rolling(window = 32)
r['msprice'].plot(color='red')
```

However, this code:

```
r = df1.rolling(window = 32).apply(lambda x : x[1] - x[2])
r['msprice'].plot(color='red')
```

gives the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Show us the full error message please. It's there for a reason. Also, are you using Python 3?

Comment: TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object
 Yes I am using Python 3

Comment: The full error; the traceback. It should look start with `Traceback (most recent call last):`. Please [edit] it into your answer.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: We need. The. Whole. Thing. Including the snippets of code shown in the traceback. That's where the information about what the error _is_ is.

Comment: Alternatively, you could produce a [mcve]; in fact, that'd be better since the error might be elsewhere. But at the very least we'll need that traceback.

Comment: The problem is when i am using lambda then i got the error. otherwise its fine

Comment: Explain "otherwise".

Comment: Otherwise)                                                                                                                
r = df1.rolling(window = 32)
r['msprice'].mean().plot(color='red')

Comment: i gives me result. but when i ma using lambda i got an error.

Comment: I've edited your question. We'll still need the actual traceback, though; what's there at the moment is completely useless.

Comment: Have you tried `r = df1.diff()`? Seeing what your data looks like might also help.

Comment: Then I Got this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Just as I thought. Your data is wrong. At this point, your problem is big enough that you'd usually pay somebody to do it; it'd take about 10 minutes of poking around to solve. Try `print(df1)`, and see if you can spot the error.

Comment: I tried print(df1), and it gives me proper result. data is perfect

Comment: Are you sure? The types of the data are wrong, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

I had a similar experience and below is my solution.

```
df['Quantity'].astype(float).rolling(window=7).mean().plot(figsize=(11,3))
```

In the column Quantity while plotting earlier it was reading values as string. converting the values to float or int is the solution.

Best Regards